# setInterval as counter doesn't work with Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

When I am trying to use setInterval as counter and next I am trying to use cy.clock/cy.tick it changes the time but setInterval doesn't changes;

Code to reproduce: https://github.com/EddyRock/vue-cypress

Comment: Please explain as much of the problem as you can here, locally at Stack Overflow, directly in your question.  What did you find out when you debugged it?

Comment: Additionally, what do you expect to change about setInterval? Do you want it to run more often or less often? If so, you'll have to pass a variable with the time as setInterval's second argument rather than hardcoding a value of ```1000```.

Comment: I think it should work faster.  For example if you used cy.tick(30000) it would work 30 times after the command.  Should I rewrite logic here? Or there is a bug?